# How to "draw" a ROC curve

Tags: self-study, roc

I have read [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256648/draw-roc-curve-on-an-example-of-10-probability-scores) but it doesn't have any well-explained answer for this case: I understand the ROC curve in overall, but I'm looking for a step-to-step explanation in order to understand how the curve changes when one true-positive becomes false-positive (and so on). For example, how can I draw a ROC curve with this set?. Does the score means the "certainty" for the value given? (for example: for the `id == A` the is a `0.03` of certainty that the value is `active/decoy == a`?)

```
id  score   active/decoy 
A   0.03    a
B   0.08    a
C   0.10    d
C   0.11    a
D   0.22    d
E   0.32    a
F   0.35    a
G   0.43    a
H   0.57    a
I   0.61    d
J   0.68    a
```

Comment: Did you read this question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145566/how-to-calculate-area-under-the-curve-auc-or-the-c-statistic-by-hand Can you be more specific about which part you do not understand?

Comment: Start with a cutoff of 0.001. If the score is above the cutoff, mark is "d". Otherwise, mark it "a". Determine the sensitivity and 1-specificity. Do it again for a cutoff of 0.002. Do it again for a cutoff...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general algorithm I have used in the past to draw ROC

1. Sort the data by `score` from lowest to highest
2. Choose lowest `score` as the cut-point
3. Calculate sensitivity and specificity using the cut-point from step 2. Save sensitivity and 1-specificity
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 for each unique `score` from lowest to highest
5. Create a step plot where the x-axis is 1-specificity and the y-axis is sensitivity

I would recommend re-coding `active/decoy` as 0/1 for the algorithm